# git - create a new branch from local copy and then merge it with existing branch

Tags: git, version-control, gitlab, git-merge, pull

Being a git newbie, I have messed up a little bit in the way I handled a new development and I do not succeed in resolving this properly.

I have a `master` branch.
I made a local copy of this `master` branch on my desktop computer and then I removed the hidden `.git` folder (don't ask me why).
I did quite some work on this local copy and I also updated the `master` branch to resolve some bugs and pushed the changes.

Now I want to create a new branch `new_version` for this new branch on which I worked locally.
Then I want to merge the modifications from `master` into `new_version`.

How can I do that ?

In my local branch I tried the following which ended up in a total mess:

```
git init
git pull my_repo master
```

So I reverted to the initital state where this local new branch was not even a git repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean that you made a local copy of the root folder and worked on it (without the .git directory), simply go back to the original directory and make sure you are up to date with `git pull`.  Then, take your local copy and copy it over the original directory (making sure, again, that there is no .git directory in your copy). Then, simply commit your changes with `git add .` and `git commit`.

Comment: well, the thing is I want to keep my original copy (master branch) as-is and create a new branch for the local copy on which I have unfinished work. Can I instead copy the master branch dir into the new one and then push on a new branch ?

Comment: Sure, just do a `git checkout -b new-branch-name` after you pull.

Answer (score 0):

First create a branch from the point where you made a copy of your master branch

```
git branch <branch name> <sha1>
```

Then copy all of your files from your copy into the working copy, all your changes should now show as diffs.

```
git commit -am'new stuff made'
```

Commit your changes and then rebase from master to have all recent changes applied

```
git rebase master
```